# What is the difference between sql server 2008 64 bit and sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can you please explain what does a SQL Server 64 bit version brings into the table which a regular 32-bit doesnot have? In other words, why should I invest in 64-bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It brings you all the advantages of a 64 bit application has over a 32 bit application. Do you know what that mean?

Mainly it starts on a hardware level by the way the CPU) handles information. For example, a 32 bit CPU can only handle 2^32 bist, which limits it to 2Gb of RAM. The 64-bit can handle 2^64, which is a very large amounts of  memory. You can easily conclude that any hardware improvement will positively affect every software that runs over it and SQL Server is no exception.

Answer (score 3):

> SQL Server 64 bit version brings into the table which a regular 32-bit doesnot have? In other words, why should I invest in 64-bit?

It is the amount of memory that 2008 can use.  In a 32-bit version it's limited to only a few gigabytes where the 64bit version can use much much more. In the 32 bit version, the server has to access the hardrive for database information much much more, the 64-bit OS and enough memory allows the server to hold much more of the database in memory, making the queries faster.